# A Type-3 If clause with simple past?

Tags: conditional-constructions

What's the type of this IF clause:

> If she didn't want to get into an argument, Valerie would have followed the majority undoubtedly.

It seems it's [type 3](https://www.ef.edu/english-resources/english-grammar/type-3-conditional/) but the if statement in the sentence not match with  the standard pattern (past perfect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mixed conditionals that combine simple past in the conditional and conditional perfect in the result usually refer to a **present** condition and a **past** result:

- If she didn't like arguments, she would have avoided the situation. (However, she **does like** arguments and, as a result, she **didn't avoid** the situation.)

I can only understand the sentence proposed if the past tense is understood as **real past**:

*If she didn't want to get into an argument, Valerie would have followed the majority undoubtedly = If Valerie wasn't willing to get into an argument, then she would have followed the majority.* (The meaning is that she didn't object to the idea of having an argument and thus did not follow the majority.)

This is another alternative, with a different meaning:

- If she didn't want to get into an argument, Valerie **should** have followed the majority. (The point is, however, that Valerie did not follow the majority and thus got into an argument.)